# How to display a specific Local Distribution Zone (LDZ) and hover/click to have the targetted region information using OpenLayers extension?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

There are several **regions** over UK:
North East, North West, Yorkshire and The Humber, East Midlands, West Midlands, East of England, London, South East, and South West.

A user will focus a region and see pre-defined information for it as shown below:

[image]

What is the best OpenLayers extension to achieve that, using OpenLayers?

There are several other [examples over OpenLayers examples catalog](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/)

[CartoDB](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cartodb.html) colors entire countries, I am looking for color fill, but for smaller regions and filtering by regions from UK.

Comment: Please do not ask for "best" extensions, APIs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a [codepen](https://codepen.io/r0ss_01/pen/zbrGdG) that does exactly what I am looking for:

```
No need for OpenLayers in this case.
```